# GooglePlay - Application now being displayed in the list

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app in GooglePlay. It used to be in 36th position of the Tools -> Top New Free list. I have released 4 versions of the application previously and every time it stayed in the list. After the last update, the application just popped off the list and is not being displayed. Everything in the application is same except the functionalities.

Here is what I know, from my experience..
If the application is updated or released in the last 30 days, and its doing good then it stays in the top free list.

Even if it only stays for 30 days from the date of release of the first version, its not been 30 days since the first release (first release was on Jan 17th 2013).

Let's say my application is doing really bad (Lots and lots of errors and people aren't using it..) But even then, it should have been in the list, the first day it was updated.

What could be the reason? Did anyone face this issue?

Is releasing a new version, a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the application is updated or released in the last 30 days, and its doing good then it stays in the top free list.

I believe this is not true.  Updating an app does not keep it as "New".  An app is marked as "New" for a set amount of time after the initial release and then it drops off.

Comment: Are you sure about the 30 days?

Comment: i suppose it could have been dropped off for many reasons, but google doesn't make their ranking criteria public that I know of.  maybe after 5 updates they no longer consider an app new.